# Memory Leaks & OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

So I am trying to find out why my app is crashing for

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 128887990 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 76MB until OOM
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
```

I have read several post but they all point towards a bitmap image, I am not using any bitmaps, so then I thought maybe I have memory leaks which might cause this, so I installed leakcanary and it is only showing the following leak:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfi.zzfus
references com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzci.zzful
references com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzck.zzfuk
com.tech.activity.dashboard instance
```

I have searched on Google, Stackoverflow, Github and leak canary and I can not find reference to what this is exactly leaking or how to fix it. I believe this is coming from my `google play services location`, but could this cause my OOM error I am seeing? Can someone point me in the right direction?

** EDIT ** 
As a comment pointed out this is supposed to be a string builder issue, I have never changed how my string builder works since I first released the app, here is my `Stringbuilder` which the source comes from `AccessibilityNodeInfo`, am I doing something wrong here?

```
public void processEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    processSubEvent(source, 0, sb);

    processUIText(source, sb.toString().toLowerCase());
}

private void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final int n, final StringBuilder sb) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        sb.append("\t");
    }

    if (source != null){
        sb.append(tools.getText(source));
        sb.append("\n");
        final int childCount = source.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Last UI: " + lastUIText);
            AccessibilityNodeInfo child = source.getChild(i);
            processSubEvent(child, n + 1, sb);

            child.recycle();
            }
        }
}
```

This is example how the information is being used:

```
private void processUIText(AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final String text)
{
   if (text.contains("hello") && !text.contains("hello again"){
        tools.showToast("Hello Reached");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem with a memory leak. This is a problem with trying to allocate too much memory. 128,887,990 bytes in a single allocation is **much too large**. You need to fix whatever it is that you are doing with `StringBuilder` to not try to build such a large in-memory string.

Comment: I have updated my code, please see update, am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: The result of this depth-first recursive tree algorithm is that you are trying to generate some massive string. That is not going to work. You may need to switch to a breadth-first approach, so you can stop going deeper into the tree once your string reaches some particular size. Or, perhaps you should not be generating one big string in the first place (e.g., write this to a file, generate some other data structure).

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix this? My `sb.length()` is only showing 799 and my `childcount` is only showing 17. That doesn't seem like it would be that much memory. I have seen others post that they have over 10000.

Comment: "Any suggestion on how to fix this?" -- I already provided some. "my childcount is only showing 17" -- you have one `childcount` value per node in the tree, not just one.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added example of how I am using the code, that is as far as the text is carried in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> This is example how the information is being used:

Then don't build a string. Build a `boolean`. Something akin to this should work:

```
class Whatever {
    private boolean helloSeen=false;
    private boolean helloAgainSeen=false;

    public void processEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source)
    {
        processSubEvent(source);
    }

    private void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source) {
        if (source != null){
            String text=tools.getText(source);

            if (text.contains("hello")) {
                helloSeen=true;
            }

            if (text.contains("hello again")) {
                helloAgainSeen=true;

            }

            if (!helloSeen || !helloAgainSeen) {
                final int childCount = source.getChildCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
                {
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Last UI: " + lastUIText);
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo child = source.getChild(i);
                    processSubEvent(child);

                    child.recycle();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After `processEvent()` returns, `helloSeen` and `helloAgainSeen` will reflect whether your messages were encountered anywhere.